# jQuery & Audio API - skip to certain part with .click

Tags: jquery, api, audio, svg

Seems like a pretty easy thing to do, but I can't figure it out myself.

I'm building a Web Audio visualizer. My HTML-file consist of a SVG, ungrouped and the elements tagged within g-tags. That all works fine.

```
 <g id="start"><path fill="#f03877" d="M94.168,131.995c0,0-0.073,0.121-0.201,0.332c-0.119,0.217-0.289,0.526-0.493,0.897
    c-0.409,0.742-0.955,1.731-1.5,2.72c-0.274,0.494-0.548,0.988-0.804,1.451c-0.233,0.475-0.451,0.917-0.638,1.297
    c-0.374,0.759-0.623,1.265-0.623,1.265l-25.82-12.758c0,0,0.307-0.621,0.767-1.553c0.231-0.465,0.5-1.008,0.789-1.59
    c0.313-0.569,0.646-1.175,0.98-1.781c0.669-1.212,1.338-2.424,1.84-3.332c0.252-0.454,0.461-0.832,0.608-1.097
    c0.156-0.259,0.245-0.407,0.245-0.407L94.168,131.995z" /></g>
```

I want certain g-tags to control the current time of the song, by changing the seconds. I already have a bit of code that does that, and it works fine when I load the page.

```
  $('audio').on('canplay', function() {
    this.currentTime = 20;
});
```

Now, my question is, how do I rework that bit of code so that it works when I click one of the SVG-elements? I've already tried the jQuery click.function() which failed on me.

```
$( "#start" ).click(function() {
    $('audio').on('canplay', function() {
    this.currentTime = 20;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the object of the audio element in the page.

```
$('audio#myaudio').currentTime = 20;
```

The 'canplay' event is only triggered once, when the browser can start playing the audio, and you should not include it in the onClick.